# TensorFlow issue when running code with GPU (CUDA-11.0) on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

**Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Can someone help me solve the above problem?

When I try to execute the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
    print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

I get the following error log:

```
2021-03-07 23:47:41.236741: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
True
2021-03-07 23:47:41.953930: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-07 23:47:41.954322: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
[]
2021-03-07 23:47:41.981245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-03-07 23:47:41.981758: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 970 computeCapability: 5.2
coreClock: 1.329GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 3.94GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 208.91GiB/s
2021-03-07 23:47:41.981769: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-03-07 23:47:41.983137: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-03-07 23:47:41.983159: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-03-07 23:47:41.984153: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-03-07 23:47:41.984274: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-03-07 23:47:41.985206: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-03-07 23:47:41.985276: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-03-07 23:47:41.985339: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-03-07 23:47:41.985344: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have manually check folder **/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64** and I can't also find the mentioned file in the log **libcusparse.so.11**.

---

I've followed the official TensorFlow installation steps [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- GPU Geforce GTX 970
- Driver version 450.102.04
- Cuda Toolkit V11.0
- Cudnn V8.0.4.30 *(not completely sure how to check)*
- Python V3.7 in Anaconda venv

Comment: Your CUDA toolkit installation is broken somehow -- as per [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-major-component-versions) you should have cuSparse 11.1 and a symlink pointing to libcusparse.so.11 . If you don't, something is broken

Comment: How can I check this? If it is broken should I completely remove CUDA files from the PC (I've done it already with the "purge" command) and reinstall CUDA or reinstall the entire Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Was able to fix the problem by simply re-installing Ubuntu and using "one-liner" from [Lambda-Stack](https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software).

```
LAMBDA_REPO=$(mktemp) && \
wget -O${LAMBDA_REPO} https://lambdalabs.com/static/misc/lambda-stack-repo.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i ${LAMBDA_REPO} && rm -f ${LAMBDA_REPO} && \
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y lambda-stack-cuda
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you have? Try to execute line by line upper command (till & sign) and let us know which line failed to execute.